# document.ready in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How document.ready event is implemented in jQuery.
I mean whether  they have used defer(which does not work in old browser) option in script tag or they dynamically add script.

Comment: The `ready` event is an implementation of the various events that the browsers offer to signal that the DOM (the basic structure of the page, but not yet all images and resources) has been loaded. It works in all browsers that jQuery supports, so there is no need to worry about compatibility.

Comment: As for the implementation, see [the source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js) (search for `"bindReady:"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses feature detection and it defaults to `window.onload` if nothing better is supported:

http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery/src/event.js

Scroll down to `function bindReady() {`: